# How to optimize Win11 VM for MS Office only?

Tags: virtual-machine, performance, microsoft-office, virtualization, office365

I'd like to set up a Windows 11 VM image only for running the latest MS Office (including online collaboration features). There are lots of guides out there on how to optimize VMs, but some optimizations break Office functionality.

What can I specifically do to set up a VM that smoothly runs Office, as quickly and with as little resource wastage as possible? No problem to break/remove other unrelated Windows functionality.

EDIT: To clarify, this is a for a VM running on Parallels Desktop on an Intel Mac host with 16GB of RAM. Windows 11 runs fine, Office runs fine, but I was hoping to trim down the Windows install and eliminate the wasted resources used by unnecessary services and Windows components. Something like using VMWare's Windows OS Optimization Tool, but more granular and more suited to this particular use case.

Comment: as John said, please clarify the problems. Does the machine needs more RAM or more CPU cores? There are tools to virtualize office ( like KASM Workspaces ) but it's usually for other reasons than "getting the latest features"

Comment: If you do not process large Excel, Word files, etc., the requirements for virtual machines are not high.

Answer (score 0):

> No problem to break/remove other unrelated Windows functionality.

There is nothing to optimize.  Microsoft Office works just fine in a Windows VM. I have this running here.

Set up the Windows VM, install Office, do the normal Windows setup, and it will be good to go.

Should fit in 30 - 35 GB of VM disk space.

A reasonably standard VM setup should provide enough CPU (1 CPU 2 cores) and memory (3 - 4 GB) will work fine with most Apps including Office.

Comment: I'd say the VM's RAM/CPU 'optimisation' very much depends on what the host has to spare. I wouldn't run one with under 16GB RAM, 6 CPU, but I have 64/24 to start with.

Comment: I have 3 VMs running simultaneously, so 4 GB woks fine for each. Host has a fast SSD that also makes a big difference.